# How to get a Cell's coordinates in the delegate's painter by index/ column/row?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview, qstyleditemdelegate, qabstractitemview

Note, I'm not asking about the current cell. I'm asking about getting some OTHER cell's position by row and column.

I've set a delegate for my Qtableview to handle graphics.

Inside my paint (self, painter: QPainter, option, index: QModelIndex): I know that I can access that current cell's location using option.rect.

I'm looking to get the rect in ANOTHER cell.

I know I can get the other cell's index using index.model().index (anotherR, anotherC) but I don't know how to get the 'option' (QstyleOptionViewItem) for that other cell.

I'm using Pyqt5 is that matters.

Comment: Why do you need the "other" cell rect?

Comment: I want to draw a line from this rect to the other rect.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to draw *outside* the current opt.rect? That won't work well, as the painting on the other index will clear what was painted before.

Comment: But let's say I have cells 2,3 and cells 4,5 .  and I want to draw a line from the center of 2,3 and 4,5.   If I know the center of 2,3, and 4,5.  I can then figure out of the cells that this line have to fall on and draw this line within the cells themselves.

Comment: I would have to compile a list of all the cell's rect() to do this.   But I figure the list must already exist elsewhere already.

Comment: If you need to draw straight lines between indexes, it will be better to override the table view's paintEvent to avoid drawing artifacts, then use the [`visualRect(index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#visualRect) to get the individual index rectangles in order to draw the lines you want.

Comment: @musicamante Wow that's great advice.  Thank you.  I will try that.